# How do I identify criminals?

Tags: tropico-4

The "War on Crime" achievement in Tropico 4 instructs the player to arrest 10 criminals in a single mission. I figured there would be a list of criminals in the almanac, but no such luck. How do I identify a citizen as a criminal so I can arrest the correct people?

Comment: +1 for the title: cops have been trying to figure that out since crime was invented :)

Comment: As El Presidente, you can identify criminals by declaring them to be! C'mon, flex that absolute power.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[bwarner's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30698/how-do-i-identify-criminals/30699#30699) tipped me off to where to look. Since criminals have "Criminal" listed as their occupation, **you can find a list of them in the Residents - Job listing in the almanac under 'Criminals'**:

[image: Jobs on Tropico]

Comment: Ah, good catch.

Answer (score 6):

If you zoom in close enough to your citizens, you may see some with a yellow exclamation point over them.  Click on them, and at the top you will likely see their profession listed as "Criminal".

[image]

I'm not quite sure what causes this to appear.  I've definitely happened on people whose profession was listed as Criminal that did not have the yellow exclamation.  In fact I've really only seen it on the campaign mission where you're on an island with a bunch of criminals.  But I don't tend to be zoomed in that close, so I'm guessing it has showed up other times and I haven't noticed.  It might require you to have police and/or a prison built.  I'll add more info if I figure it out.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted, but it did hint hard enough at the answer I wanted. Check out [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30698/how-do-i-identify-criminals/30707#30707) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you build a cheap cabaret in the hood it collects all the criminals. I built one near the palace and then put out a hit and the nearby palace guards wasted them.